# How do I connect with my friend that also has shaders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have Sildur's Shaders for 1.8 the same with my friend, we also have the same Forge version same Optifine version too, How can he connect to me or me to him while having Shaders?

When we try to connect to each other using LAN (Open To Lan)
The message: "Failed to login: Access Token can not be null or empty"

We can't make a Server though

Comment: Why couldn't you use a server?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a problem with the shaders mods you have. The error "Failed to login: Access Token can not be null or empty" is an error indicating that the way you logged in to minecraft bugged out.

If the person getting that error is still logging in with their username instead of a new style account they can need to go to [Mojangs account migration page](https://account.mojang.com/migrate) and migrate to a new style account (where you log in with your email address).

If that isn't it they should try to log out and log back in again, that might fix it (it's a bit of a vague error according to my research).

Also note: I'm not 100% sure but you might get this error if you are both logging in with the same account information, you will need 2 separate Minecraft accounts.

Comment: I cannot do that BECAUSE I am NOT using Official Minecraft, nor am I using Cracked Launchers.

Comment: @Dudamesh Just so that you know, we do not offer help, if the problem is piracy spesific or if the game is admittingly pirated.